# fadeIn child on hover then fade out child on child blur

Tags: jquery

Im sure this has been asked but I have not located it.

I have li items acting as parents of child sub menu divs.

On parent li hover, the child div shows. But when I blur the parent, the child div hides.

How can I make it so that the child div will remain visible as long as the mouse cursor is over the child div, once the cursor leaves the div, the div will hide.

My code so far is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menuSection").hover(function(){
        $(this).children(".subMenuWrap").fadeIn(100);
    });
    $(".subMenuWrap").blur(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

As of now, the fadeIn works fine, they just dont dissapear on blur. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover and blur refer to different things.  Hover refers to the location of the mouse (mouseenter, mouseleave) and `blur` means the element lost `focus`.  You can give `hover` two functions, the first will be run when the user moves the mouse into the area, the second will be run when the mouse leaves:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menuSection").hover(function(){
        $(this).children(".subMenuWrap").fadeIn(100);
    },function(){
        $(this).children(".subMenuWrap").fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

Comment: huh, this works and its what I thought of doing already but I thought that the child .subMenuWrap would fade out once my mouse left the .menuSection area... Why is it that the child knows automatically to remain visible while my mouse is over it even though the hover() is really only attached to the parent area?

Comment: As long as your mouse is over the child, it is over the parent.